# run external command from vim, passing list of files from buffer

Tags: vim

In vim I have a list of files like this:

```
public/css/pure.min.css
public/css/trip.nodep.css
public/css/animate.min.css
public/css/admin-main.css
public/css/main.css
public/css/load-museo.css
public/css/upload-styles.css
public/css/pe-icon-social/css/pe-icon-social.css
public/css/pe-icon-social/css/helper.css
public/css/pe-icon-social/css/social-style.css
public/css/vex-theme-flat-attack.css
public/css/vex.css
```

How to pass those as args to an external command?

I tried `:!cleancss -o output.min.css %` but that didn't work.

EDIT:

Actually `cleancss` needs this form:

```
cat arg1 arg2 arg3... | cleancss -o minified.css
```

EDIT2:

While playing around, I found out that this worked well:

```
:!cat % | xargs cleancss -o minified.css
```

I don't know if there is some better(shorter) way of doing it.

Comment: How did you got the list of files? Through which command?

Comment: `:r !ls`, the paths are good if you are concerned about that, because `gf` works on them.

Comment: I think you can use `cat *.css | cleancss -o output.css` in shell itself. No need of vim for that. Do you still want to proceed with vim?

Comment: Sorry, actually this list will come as a result of parsing html file, so that I could concatenate specific files easily per page.. But for the purpose of this example it was read from file like a said.. so no shell in this case.

Comment: Or a bit of perl code would do. It will take files recursively and add them as arguments to cat command and then will use cleancss. Do you want to do in selected files and current folder and subdirectories?

Comment: I know how to make shell script that accepts arguments, then call it on this list.. The point is I want to do it straight from VIM

Comment: And the adverse point is that you shouldn't. That's what shells are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can join all lines first.
Keep the cursor on the desired first line and press `v` and then move using cursor till desired end line and then press `J`.
Press `gv` to reselect them and press `y` to copy.

Now, go to command line.
  Type

```
         :!cat
```

Then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> and then `"`.

It will appear like

```
         :!cat file1 file2 file3....filen
```

Then, you can type `| cleancss` and finish off the command as you know about it.

Now, it will work.

Comment: Well yes, that would work, but I was hoping for some solution not involving so many analog steps.

Comment: Actually, we are using only 6 extra keys other than the command you have given. Or, do you want it to be given like a mapping or a command or function?

Comment: Or, even a shorter way. Join all lines by pressing ggvGJ. Then, use cat % | cleancss .....